# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

Not sure what I am missing but when I add a table SEMPLOYEES in orm which has 2 @id columns, I get this error. I get this error when I use SEMPLYEES table in ORM query. Service works fine without SEMPLOYEES in ORM query but I have to get some data from this table so I have to use this. Any help will be appreciated.   Thanks!

**My entity class**

```
package com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity.keys.SEmployeesPK;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SEMPLOYEES", schema = "HRIS")
@IdClass(SEmployeesPK.class)
public class SEmployees {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "SEE_CLT_ID")
  private Long seeCltId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "SEE_EMP_NBR")
  private Integer seeEmpNbr;

  @Column(name = "SEE_LAST_NAME")
  private String seeLastName;

  @Column(name = "SEE_FIRST_NAME")
  private String seeFirstName;



    public Long getSeeCltId() {
        return seeCltId;
    }
    public void setSeeCltId(Long seeCltId) {
        this.seeCltId = seeCltId;
    }
    public Integer getSeeEmpNbr() {
        return seeEmpNbr;
    }
    public void setSeeEmpNbr(Integer seeEmpNbr) {
        this.seeEmpNbr = seeEmpNbr;
    }
    public String getSeeLastName() {
        return seeLastName;
    }
    public void setSeeLastName(String seeLastName) {
        this.seeLastName = seeLastName;
    }
    public String getSeeFirstName() {
        return seeFirstName;
    }
    public void setSeeFirstName(String seeFirstName) {
        this.seeFirstName = seeFirstName;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((seeCltId == null) ? 0 : seeCltId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((seeEmpNbr == null) ? 0 : seeEmpNbr.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((seeFirstName == null) ? 0 : seeFirstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((seeLastName == null) ? 0 : seeLastName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SEmployees other = (SEmployees) obj;
        if (seeCltId == null) {
            if (other.seeCltId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!seeCltId.equals(other.seeCltId))
            return false;
        if (seeEmpNbr == null) {
            if (other.seeEmpNbr != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!seeEmpNbr.equals(other.seeEmpNbr))
            return false;
        if (seeFirstName == null) {
            if (other.seeFirstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!seeFirstName.equals(other.seeFirstName))
            return false;
        if (seeLastName == null) {
            if (other.seeLastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!seeLastName.equals(other.seeLastName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SEmployees [seeCltId=" + seeCltId + ", seeEmpNbr=" + seeEmpNbr + ", seeLastName=" + seeLastName
                + ", seeFirstName=" + seeFirstName + "]";
    } 
}
```

===========================================================================================================

```
package com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity.keys;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SEmployeesPK implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "SEE_CLT_ID")
   private Long seeCltId;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "SEE_EMP_NBR")
   private Integer seeEmpNbr;

   public SEmployeesPK() {
   }

   public SEmployeesPK(Long seeCltId, Integer seeEmpNbr) {
      this.seeCltId = seeCltId;
      this.seeEmpNbr = seeEmpNbr;
   }

   public Long getSeeCltId() {
      return this.seeCltId;
   }

   public void setSeeCltId(Long seeCltId) {
      this.seeCltId = seeCltId;
   }

   public Integer getSeeEmpNbr() {
      return this.seeEmpNbr;
   }

   public void setSeeEmpNbr(Integer seeEmpNbr) {
      this.seeEmpNbr = seeEmpNbr;
   }



   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((seeCltId == null) ? 0 : seeCltId.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((seeEmpNbr == null) ? 0 : seeEmpNbr.hashCode());
      return result;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
         return true;
      if (obj == null)
         return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;
      SEmployeesPK other = (SEmployeesPK) obj;
      if (seeCltId == null) {
         if (other.seeCltId != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!seeCltId.equals(other.seeCltId))
         return false;
      if (seeEmpNbr == null) {
         if (other.seeEmpNbr != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!seeEmpNbr.equals(other.seeEmpNbr))
         return false;
      return true;
   }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SEmployeesPK [seeCltId=" + seeCltId + ", seeEmpNbr=" + seeEmpNbr + "]";
    } 

}
```

========================================================================

**ORM**

```
<named-native-query name="DistributionRiskAssessmentHeader.getDistributionRiskAssessmentHeader" result-class="com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity.DistributionRiskAssessmentHeader">
    <description>Get distribution risk assessment header data</description>
    <query>
    <![CDATA[
     SELECT DR_DISTRIB_ID,
            ED_PMT_METHOD,
            ED_HOLD_FLAG,
            DR_CREATED_DATE,
            HH_ID,
            DR_SSN,
            ED_PAYEE_FIRST_NAME,
            ED_PAYEE_LAST_NAME
       FROM KIS.DISTRIBUTION_REQUESTS,
            KIS.EMPLOYEE_DISTRIBUTIONS,
            LNDRISK.HISTORY_HEADER,
            HRIS.SEMPLOYEEPLAN,
            HRIS.SEMPLOYEES
      WHERE DR_DISTRIB_ID = :in_distribution_id`enter code here`
            AND ED_DISTRIB_ID = DR_DISTRIB_ID
            AND HH_DISBURSEMENT_ID = DR_DISTRIB_ID
            AND ED_PLAN_ID = SEP_PLAN_ID
            AND SEP_CLT_ID = SEE_CLT_ID
            AND SEP_EMP_NBR = SEE_EMP_NBR
    ]]>
    </query>
  </named-native-query>
```

========================================================================================

**Repository**

```
package com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity.SEmployees;
import com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.entity.keys.SEmployeesPK;

public interface SEmployeesRepository extends CrudRepository<SEmployees, SEmployeesPK> {
}
```

====================================================================================================

**Error**

```
[ERROR] 2020-04-05 21:54:22 o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8084-exec-1]: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

[ERROR] 2020-04-05 21:54:22 c.p.h.r.q.DistributionRiskAssessmentHistoryQueryHandler [http-nio-8084-exec-1]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested
 exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy162.getDistributionRiskAssessmentHeader(Unknown Source)
        at com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.query.DistributionRiskAssessmentHistoryQueryHandler.handle(DistributionRiskAssessmentHistoryQueryHandler.java:82)
        at com.paychex.hrs.riskassessment.query.DistributionRiskAssessmentHistoryQueryHandler.handle(DistributionRiskAssessmentHistoryQueryHandler.java:43)
        at com.paychex.serviceframework.query.impl.RegisteredQueryHandlerDispatcher.dispatch(RegisteredQueryHandlerDispatcher.java:93)
        at com.paychex.serviceframework.query.QueryDispatcherImpl.dispatch(QueryDispatcherImpl.java:25)
        at com.paychex.serviceframework.query.QueryProcessorImpl.execute(QueryProcessorImpl.java:38)
        at com.paychex.serviceframework.query.QueryProcessorImpl.execute(QueryProcessorImpl.java:32)
        at com.paychex.hrs.distributionmanager.rest.DistributionRiskAssessmentController.getDistributionRiskAssessment(DistributionRiskAssessmentController.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2265)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2028)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2254)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:765)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:921)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1099)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3687)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.oracle$1ucp$1jdbc$1proxy$1StatementProxy$2oracle$1jdbc$1internal$1OraclePreparedStatement$$$Proxy.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.paychex.hrs.traceability.dao.jdbc.StatementTracer.log(StatementTracer.java:129)
        at com.paychex.hrs.traceability.dao.jdbc.StatementTracer.invoke(StatementTracer.java:76)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy211.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        ... 110 more
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 222, Sql = SELECT DR_DISTRIB_ID, ED_PMT_METHOD, ED_HOLD_FLAG, DR_CREATED_DATE, HH_ID, DR_SSN, SEE_FIRST_NAME, SEE_LAST_NAME FROM KIS.DISTRIBUTION_REQUESTS, KIS.EMPLOYEE_DISTRIBUTIONS,
LNDRISK.HISTORY_HEADER, HRIS.SEMPLOYEEPLAN, and bla bla bla ........
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use several identifiers for your object , you should use @EmbeddedId

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html

Also @Embeddable should be present on class which would be injected via @EmbeddedId

Please refer to example:

http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-embeddedid-example/

Comment: I would recommend doing this instead, is how we do it in our project.

Comment: All is correct , but are you using @Embeddable annotation ?

Comment: Moskura, I'm not the one with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are using @Id on the class used as Id for SEmployees.
try modifying SEmployeesPK to:

```
public class SEmployeesPK implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

   private Long seeCltId;

   private Integer seeEmpNbr;

   .
   .
   .
```

The error must have been caused because SEmployeesPK table does not exists.

Hope this help, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.  if I will take SEMPLOYEES table out from the ORM query then it works.  As I add this table and condition related to this table which is AND SEP_CLT_ID = SEE_CLT_ID
            AND SEP_EMP_NBR = SEE_EMP_NBR.  Then I get the error.  Not sure why??

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be with different table(might not exists or grant privilege is not for that table) mapped due to foreign key or synonym.

For me the issue was with a column in that table which had mapping with another schema-table, and it was missing.ex, public-synonym.